# Increasing a number by 1 using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.fav').live('click', function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    //increase the number by 1
```

html:

```
<li class="fav light_gray_serif">5</li>
```

how can i use jquery to increase the number between the li  everytime its clicked? thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var num = parseInt($.trim($(this).html()));
$(this).html(++num)
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to take a look at [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Here is an example:

```
$(this).text(function(i, t) {
    return Number(t) + 1;
});
```

Comment: +1, this is by far the best answer (owing to the use of `Number` instead of `parseInt`, and `text()` instead of `html()`), but no upvotes so far?

Comment: @box9 Care to explain why `Number` is better than `parseInt`? http://jsperf.com/number-vs-parseint-vs-plus/7 And why is `text()` better than `html()`?

Comment: @The Scrum, the point about `Number` vs `parseInt` really depends, but typically `Number` is more semantically correct as it rejects strings such as `1abc2` whereas `parseInt` will still parse the first part. Again, `text()` is more semantically correct, as it represents the human-readable part of the document, but also safer in case someone decides to wrap the number in a span for whatever purpose (from a reading point of view; for output, it really doesn't matter unless your string needs escaping).

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<span id="counter">0</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#counter').text(Number($('#counter').text())+1);
```

You can increase the counter when clicking an existing button like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#your-button', function(){
  $('#counter').text(Number($('#counter').text())+1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a plugin.

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.fn, {
         "addOne": function() {
              var num = parseInt(this.text(), 10);
              this.text(++num);
         },
         "subtractOne": function() {
              var num = parseInt(this.text(), 10);
              this.text(--num);
         }
    });
}(jQuery))
```

Then call

```
$(".fav").live("click", function(e) {
     $(this).toggleClass("highlight").addOne();
});
```